# The email address is badly formatted. Flutter? Unable to resolve the issue/

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I am trying to make an authentication using flutter and firebase and i always face this problem. I have enabled email and password authetication in firebase and also addded the SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys,but still not able to resolve the error.
I am getting the error that 'The email is badly formmated.'
The error is given below.

```
W/DynamiteModule( 7351): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 7351): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
I/DynamiteModule( 7351): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 7351): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /SignUp
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 7351): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
I/FirebaseAuth( 7351): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
W/System  ( 7351): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter ( 7351): [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.
```

Here goes the form validation page.

```
    
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_final_fields, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:howyoudoin/controller/auth_methods.dart';
import 'package:howyoudoin/utils/theme.dart';
import 'package:howyoudoin/widgets/widgets.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _username = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _bioController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(),
                flex: 1,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _username,
                hintText: "UserName",
                textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                isPass: false,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _emailController,
                hintText: "Enter Your Email",
                textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                isPass: false,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _passwordController,
                hintText: "Password",
                textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                isPass: true,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _bioController,
                hintText: "Bio",
                textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                isPass: false,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
                    email: _emailController.toString(),
                    password: _passwordController.toString(),
                    username: _username.toString(),
                    bio: _bioController.toString(),
                  );
                  print(res);
                },
                child: Text("Sign Up"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: blueColor,
                  minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 50),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(),
                flex: 1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the AuthMethod Code is

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:howyoudoin/resources/storage_methods.dart';

class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<String> signUpUser(
      {required String email,
      required String password,
      required String username,
      required String bio}) async {
    String res = "Some error occured";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty ||
          password.isNotEmpty ||
          bio.isNotEmpty ||
          username.isNotEmpty) {
        UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        print(cred.user!.uid);
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(cred.user!.uid).set({
          'username': username,
          'uid': cred.user!.uid,
          'email': email,
          'bio': bio
        });
        res = "success";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res = err.toString();
    }

    return res;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Calling `toString()` on a `TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier/toString.html) gives you a description of the controller, not the value of the underlying text field. So this seems wrong:

```
  String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
    email: _emailController.toString(),
    password: _passwordController.toString(),
    username: _username.toString(),
    bio: _bioController.toString(),
  );**
```

To [get the value of the actual text field](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input#3-display-the-current-value-of-the-text-field), use the `text` property of the controller instead. So:

```
  String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
    email: _emailController.text,
    password: _passwordController.text,
    username: _username.text,
    bio: _bioController.text,
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is very simple.. you are using:

```
email: _emailController.toString(),
                password: _passwordController.toString(),
                username: _username.toString(),
                bio: _bioController.toString(),
```

but you should be using

```
email: _emailController.text,
                password: _passwordController.text,
                username: _username.text,
                bio: _bioController.text,
```

kindly upvote if useful

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead in the `AuthMethod` Code for signup. Basically, if we provide an email address with a space, then the authentication error occurs. The trim method will remove any extra whitespace.

```json
{
    'username':username.trim(),
    'uid':credential.user!.uid,
    'name':name.trim(),
    'email':email.trim(),
    'bio': bio.trim()
}
```